# How to get svn revision number using exec() and command in PHP?

Tags: php, svn

I need svn revision number from PHP script. I have used the following commands with exec(). But it does not return any thing.

```
$value = exec("usr/bin/svn --username myusername--password mypassword info /home/mysite/mysite_www/mysite |grep Revision: |cut -c11-", $output, $status);
```

or

```
$value = exec("svn info |grep Revision: |cut -c11-", $output, $status);
```

I have also tried using share script but no result.
Please guide me how to get a SVN revision number using PHP and the command.

Comment: This doesn't really have one single thing to do with Javascript, does it?

Comment: Your second example works fine here (i prefer `| awk '/Revision:/{print $2}'`, but that's a personal choice), if it doesn't work it's most likely a file-permission problem.

Comment: I added JavaScript so that if a solution is available in javascript i can use it. And the whole scenario appeared because of javascript cache problem.

Second example was not giving any result as in my case. Thanks anyway for your remarks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the SVN revision number from the .svn/entries file using something like the following code snippet.

```
// open .svn/entries file
$content = file_get_contents("/path/to/your/site/.svn/entries");

// get revision number
$lines = explode("\n", $content, 12);
$revision = intval($lines[10]);

// print out the revision number
echo "Revision: " . $revision;
```

Using this, you could also get the date by parsing the content of `$lines[11]`

Comment: Relying on .svn internals (as in: the entries file) should be considered dangerous: svn may update it's format, and at that moment svn still works like a charm but your code breaks. For instance, in svn 1.1 it used to be XML in there...

Comment: Also, currently line a 4 (index 3) holds the _current_ revision. Line 11 (idx 10) would be the 'last changed revision'....

Comment: @Wrikken : You are correct, regarding the index of revision number.

Comment: Well, I'm also correct regarding the format of the `entries` file having changed over time and any manual parsing being unreliable :P